# HAProxy SSL-termination with redirect http to https is losing X-Client-IP information with send-proxy to NGINX

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, haproxy, lxd

**ISSUE**

I can't see the original *remote-ip* coming from outside, when I use SSL-Termination in HAProxy and force HTTPS. If I do not force HTTP to HTTPS redirect, I can see from nginx-logs that send-proxy is in fact working with HTTP. I can see the same thing from HAProxy-logs too.

**THEORY**

If I remove all cookies of the site, switch redirect off and open the HTTP version, HAProxy will show the *remote-ip* correctly. After switching redirect to HTTPS and opening the same HTTP-site, logs will first show a connection from *remote-ip* to backend:

```
    176.93.182.162:49300 [14/Feb/2020:23:40:30.254] 80_443_frontend 80_443_frontend/(NOSRV)
```

and then a connection from localhost (127.0.0.1):

```
    127.0.0.1:35304 [14/Feb/2020:23:40:30.776] 80_443_frontend~ 80_443_backend/git 0/0/0/1/1 200
```

**CONCLUSION**

My thoughts are, that HAProxy will direct internal traffic from 443 back to port 80 towards the backend, and at the same time switch the header IP to it's own IP. Hopefully someone will have an idea.

HAProxy is inside it's own lxd container, as is NGINX!! If this changes something?

This is the configuration in HAProxy:

```
    frontend 80_443_frontend
        bind *:80
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/git.domain.org/git.domain.org.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
        redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
        timeout client 1m
        option forwardfor
        option http-server-close
        acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
        use_backend letsencrypt_backend if letsencrypt-acl
        acl git_host hdr(host) -i git.domain.org

        use_backend 80_443_backend if git_host

    backend letsencrypt_backend
        server letsencrypt 127.0.0.1:8888

    backend 80_443_backend
        http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[src]
        server git git.lxd:80 send-proxy
```

Comment: This is from the HAProxy log with HTTPS redirect on: **Connect from 127.0.0.1:35314 to 127.0.0.1:443 (80_443_frontend/HTTP)**

Comment: This is from the HAProxy log with HTTP redirect off: **Connect from 176.93.182.162:49651 to 10.4.21.53:80 (80_443_frontend/HTTP)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, f*ck me sideways!

One needs to remember what ports are forwarded to containers!!

**This is what was missing:**

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p TCP -d PUBLIC_IP/32 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.4.21.53:443
```